# Can I bypass the child and go grandchild to parent? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am wondering if it is at all possible to fire an event in the grandchild and trigger something in the overall parent, without having to go through the middle step child.

I have created a simple example that will simply console.log the layer

So I am wanting to go Grandchild => Parent (Fire event) instead of going Grandchild => Child => Parent (Fire event)

If this is not possible in a simple way such as going up the chain, then do let me know.

**Parent**

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Parent
        <Child clickMe={this.fireEvent.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

  fireEvent() {
    console.log("Parent")
  }
}
```

**Child**

```
export default class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        child
        <Grandchild fireEvent={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    )

  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('Child')
    this.props.clickMe();
  }
}
```

**Grandchild**

```
export default class Grandchild extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        grandchild
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>GC Click</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('Grandchild')
    this.props.fireEvent();
  }
}
```

Comment: Not possible with vanilla React.

Comment: @Chris - Could this be done by calling either <Child/> or <Grandchild/> with props={this.props}?

Comment: Maybe look into context, with this you don't have to go though all the chains in your component graph. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html. But that might be overkill for your purpose. You could also use a flux library such as Redux, might also be overkill for your purpose.

Comment: @Kunukn - Thanks for the link - would be useful in future I think ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To interact with components that  are not direct children, you can use redux or [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Context is an experimental API and should be used if you have no other choice.

Here is an example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import User from './User';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Small extends React.Component {

    static contextTypes = {
        color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    render() {
        return <div style={{backgroundColor: this.context.color, height: '125px', width: '33%'}}>
            Small, user = {this.context.user.id}-{this.context.user.login}
        </div>;
    }
}

class Medium extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div style={{backgroundColor: 'red', height: '250px', width: '50%'}}>
            Medium
            <Small/>
        </div>;
    }
}

export default class Large extends React.Component {

    static childContextTypes = {
        color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    getChildContext() {
        return {color: 'purple', user: new User(1, 'admin')};
    }

    render() {
        return <div style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', color: 'white', height: '300px', width: '75%'}}>
            Large
            <Medium/>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the way I had once seen is almost a cheating method of bypassing a certain layer, bu passing the parent props themselves as props within the child to the grandchild...

**Parent**

```
<child propsToChild={this.someFunction.bind(this)}/>

someFunction() { console.log("parent"); }
```

**Child**

```
<grandchild propsToGrandchild={this.props}/>
```

**Grandchild**

```
<button onClick={ this.grandChildClick.bind(this) }>Click me</button>

grandChildClick() { 
    console.log("Grandchild");
    this.props.propsToGrandchild.propsToChild()
}
```

**[Demonstration](https://codesandbox.io/s/olxzl9k89y)**

---

**ALSO...**

I have found that it is much easier to spread your props through the layers. This can be shown by editing the `Child` class as such:

```
render() {
    const props = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        Child
        <Grandchild {...props}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```